# Partial search in multidimensional array not working in depth elements

Tags: php, php-7

Hello I have a result like this from API:

```
$data = [
"1" => [
    "book" => "Harry Potter",
    "artist" => array("David", "Emma"),
    "country" => [
        ["description" => "Wander"],
        ["description" => "Magic"]
    ]
],
"2" => [
    "book" => "Science book",
    "artist" => array("Artist 1", "Melanie Hudson"),
    "country" => [
        ["description" => "Physics"],
        ["description" => "Albert Einstein"]
    ]
],
"3" => [
    "book" => "Bible",
    "artist" => array("Artist 1", "Pedro"),
    "country" => [
        ["description" => "Love"],
        ["description" => "Respect"]
    ]
],
];
```

What I am doing is to search partially for a string value using PHP in a multidimensional Array. It's working when I search the `book` values (e.g Potter). But when it comes to `artist` and `country`. My codes is not working anymore. The search will return all the matches.
Below is what I've done so far:

```
function searchFor($haystack, $needle)
{
$r = array();
foreach($haystack as $key => $array) {
$contains = false;
foreach($array as $k => $value) {

       if (!is_array($value)) {
           if(stripos($value, $needle) !== false ) {
              $contains = true;
           }
       }

       else {
           searchFor($array['country'],$needle);
       }
  }

   if ($contains) {
      array_push($r,$array);
   }
  }

   return $r;
 }


echo ("<pre>");

print_r(searchFor($data,"Wander"));   <--- Not working. but when I change it to Potter it will work.

echo ("</pre>");
```

Any idea how can I improve my codes will be much appreciated.
Note: I am trying to reduce the use of many loops and built in functions of PHP. I just want a simple but efficient solution for this. Hopefully someone will share some idea. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following logic might help you on your way:

```
$result = []; // $result is container for matches - filled by reference
$needle = 'Wander'; // the value we are looking for
recurse($data, $needle, $result);

function recurse($haystack = [], $needle = '', &$result) {
    foreach($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            recurse($value, $needle, $result);
        } else {
            if(strpos($value, $needle) !== false) {
                $result[] = $value; // store match
            }
        }
    }
}
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/E6LT6)

Answer (score 1):

You need to merge the results of your recursive call to `searchFor` with your result `$r`. Try this in the `else` statement with your recursive call to `searchFor`:

```php
else {
    $r = array_merge($r, searchFor($array['country'],$needle));
}
```